# How do I remove the background of a Tab Bar in react nativegation v6?

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-native-navigation

[I applied borderTopLefRadius and borderTopRightRadius: So this is the result of my custom tab navigator, but I want to remove that white background color, but I don´t know how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHjY7.png)

This is my code:

```
        <Tabs.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarStyle: {
                borderTopRightRadius: 15,
                borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
                height: 60,
            },                  
        }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a theme with a transparent background to your NavigationContainer:

```html
<NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
  <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
    tabBarStyle: {
      borderTopRightRadius: 15,
      borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
      height: 60,
      },                  
    }}
  >
  {/* screens */}
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>

const navigationTheme = {
  colors: {
    background: "transparent",
  },
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I have already found the solution:

```
    <Tabs.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarStyle: styles.tab,
            tabBarLabelStyle: styles.label,
        }}
        sceneContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: colors.background }}
    >
```